# Rotating videos in SDAVAssetExportSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, avassetexportsession, avmutablecomposition, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I currently use `SDAVAssetExportSession` to join videos together and apply fades between the transitions.

However, when I record a video with the front-facing camera, `SDAVAssetExportSession` does not take the rotation (180 degrees) of the front-facing videos into account and as a result I get a joined together video that has parts that are upside-down.

What is the best method to get `SDAVAssetExportSession` to rotate only these front-facing assets so that the outputted video is all in the correct orientation?

Edit:

I am currently capturing video data via the `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput`.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I just had to provide a VideoComposition to go into the SDAVAssetExportSession and then detect rotation of each video asset when generating the composition.